# How to access the data in this PHP XML response?

Tags: php, xml

I'm doing a request to a gov't website for validating a tax number. I get a pretty nested XML response and i'm pretty frustrated at the moment trying to parse and access the data.

In essense this is the response:

```
 <params>
    <param>
        <value><array><data>
            <value><string>UstId_1</string></value>
            <value><string>SOMETAXNUM</string></value>
        </data></array></value>
    </param>
    <param>
        <value><array><data>
            <value><string>ErrorCode</string></value>
            <value><string>200</string></value>
        </data></array></value>
    </param>
    <param>
         <value><array><data>
            <value><string>UstId_2</string></value>
            <value><string>SECONDTAXNUM</string></value>
         </data></array></value>
    </param> ....

</params>
```

I parse the result with `new SimpleXMLElement()` .

But i have no success accessing what i truely need... And what i need is the "ErrorCode" Response (in this case its 200).

This is what i had

```
$xml->["param"][1]->["value"]->['array']->["data"]->["value"‌​][1]->['string'];
```

Thanks to the answer i got, this is my poor solution to get the code i wanted:

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
        $result = $xml->xpath('param');

        $count = 0;
        while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
            if ($count == 1){
                return (string)$node->value[0]->array[0]->data->value[1]->{'string'};
            }
            $count ++;
        }
```

Comment: Show us your unsuccessful attempt to see if we can salvage anything from it.

Comment: $xml->["param"][1]->["value"]->['array']->["data"]->["value"][1]->['string'];

Comment: Please put it in your OP instead.

Comment: Which gov't?  Is PHP common there?

Comment: Tony -> German ;-).  They got this access point to check if a Tax num is valid

Comment: So the results are sequential in the returned XML? There's no relationship via embedding or reference in the node structure. Odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#With something like this

$xml = simplexml_load_string ($xmlstring);
$result = $xml->xpath('param');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo (string)$node->value[0]->array[0]->data->value[0]->{'string'};#UstId_1
}
```

By the way, very ugly and bad XML example file that you have here. 
:)
 Please fromat the xml litte better in you question.

Comment: Thank You - Yes, its a very bad result and i lost quite a bit of hair trying to figure it out.   I managed to 'jimmy' your statement to get the code i want. I'll accept your answer and my 'workaround' as "good enough" :D  Thanks  (going to put my 'workaround' in the OP in a minute)

Comment: JustOnUnderMillion -> I'm really happy that i found a 'solution', but not understanding it is bugging me. I've been reading on php.net about lists and i for example dont understand why the first spot was skipped. Also why can't i access the 'spot' directly without a while statement and assigning it to a list? The desired value i need is always in the same spot in the result set. Like if i use `$result->param[1]->value[0]->array[0]->data->value[1]->{'string'};` it throws errors about undefined, but to me the 'steps' look fine??  Sorry if i'm confusing, just trying to learn. Thanks

Comment: @Matt `each($result)` returns an array with ley and value like `[$key,$value]` of the current iteration. And `list(,$node)` takes only the value of that.

Comment: @Matt Little hint an SimpleXMLElement: lets say you have an field with one or more entries. If only one is given you can just do `$xml->field` if you have more you have to do `$xml->field[0]` to get the same entriy. Read about that Tpoic: How to iterate and ahndle SimpleXML Correctly. And always do `var_dump();` and see the Objekt/Array Structurce for yourself. :)